# Javascript: Calling function inside a loop = unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to loop trying to loop through an array in javascript, (jQuery), and pass each key to a separate function.

This works fine, except when I want to factor in a half second delay between function calls for flood protection. When I do this it stops functioning as expected, and only passes the last key to the function instead of the current one?

Please see my simplified example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    var delay = 500;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        delay = 500 + delay;
        setTimeout(function(){
            output( key );
        }, delay );
    }
});

function output( val ) {
    $('#results').append( val );
}
```

Expected

```
123456789
```

Produced

```
999999999
```

---

## Stranger still...

I assumed that this was because the 'key' value was being overwritten each loop, so by the time the Timeout functions trigger, the 'key' is always set to '9'. So I tried not overwriting 'key', but using an array and setting a new 'key' each time, like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
    var delay = 0;
    var key = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        delay++;
        key[delay] = arr[i];
        setTimeout(function(){
            output( key[delay] );
        }, 500*delay );
    }
});

function output( val ) {
    $('#results').append( val );
}
```

This still produces the result:

```
999999999
```

So:

- Why does this happen when 'key[delay]' should be a different value each time 'delay' is incremented and the Timeout function is set?
- How can I achieve the results that I am trying to, where the key is different each time the Timeout function is triggered?

Comment: Infamous loop problem.

Comment: One of the links on the right is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1 which should help.

Comment: The second example has the same problem because `delay` changes in each iteration.